# How to find $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{1-x^2}$ without using differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is: Find the limit **without using differentiation.**

$$ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{1-x^2}        $$

A solution I saw was the following:

1. Compute the limit from the right side $1+h$

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{1-(1+h)^2} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{-h^2-2h}  $$

As $h$ goes to $0$ that will approach  negative infinity.

2. Now form the left hand side:

$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{1-(1-h)^2} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{2h-h^2}  $$

This limit does not converge as from the left side it goes to -infinity and from the right side to positive infinity as h goes to 0.

So can I conclude that for $$ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{1-x^2}        $$
the limit does not converge since from approaching $1$ from the right side and left side is not equal, i. e. $f(1+h)\neq f(1-h)$ ? Or is there a simple algebraic manipulation I am missing?

Comment: All fine as you wrote it.

Comment: The title doesn't make sense. Derivatives don't have any role here.

Comment: The relation between $f(1+h)$ and $f(1-h)$ has nothing to do with the limit $h\to 0$. It can be $=$ and it can be $\neq$. The key point is 1) that the limits $\lim  f(1+h)$ and $f(1-h)$ don't exist in $\mathbb{R}$ as $h\to 0$ downwards and 2) they aren't equal in $\mathbb{R}\cup\lbrace \pm \infty\rbrace$.

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy is fine, but can be shortened. Since $1-x^2\to0$ from both sides, its reciprocal $\to\pm\infty$ depending on the side, with the implications you already noted.